# Unable to send upload url

Tags: media

I have created an image uploader, when I click the submit button the media uploader pop-up box appears but the image path is not being sent to the input field.

Display code:

```
    <label for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></label>
<input name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" type="<?php echo $value['type']; ?>" value="<?php if ( get_settings( $value['id'] ) != "") { echo stripslashes(get_settings( $value['id'])  ); } else { echo $value['std']; } ?>" />
```

My image uploader class:

```
array( "name" => "Logo URL",
"desc" => "Enter the link to your logo image",
"id" => $shortname."_logo",
"type" => "upload",
"std" => ""),
```

Comment: "upload" is not a valid input type attribute. Have you tried using "file".

Comment: I am using wordpress uploader.Why not valid option framework used "upload"